# How to use Mina in Snap svg?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

This is an animation code using Snap svg:

```
var s = Snap(3000,3000);

var circle7 = s.circle(130,90,5);
var circle8 = s.circle(155,90,5);
var circle9 = s.circle(180,90,5);
var circle10 = s.circle(205,90,5);
var circle11 = s.circle(230,90,5);
var circle12 = s.circle(255,90,5);


circle.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle1.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle2.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle3.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle4.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle5.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle6.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle7.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle8.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle9.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle10.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle11.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});
circle12.attr({fill:"#ffffff",opacity:0});

circle.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},4500);
circle1.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},4000);
circle2.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},3500);
circle3.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},3000);
circle4.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},2500);
circle5.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},2000);
circle6.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},1500);

circle7.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},4500);
circle8.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},5000);
circle9.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},5500);
circle10.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},6000);
circle11.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},6500);
circle12.animate({fill:"#0000FF",opacity:1},7000);

var cloud = s.image("D:/DigiMKey/login page_files/cloud.png", 0 , 260, 180, 
125);
cloud.attr({opacity:0,width:100,height:65});
cloud.animate({opacity:1,width:200,height:125},1000)

var school =s.image("D:/DigiMKey/images/School-Icon.png", 265, 50, 100,100);
school.attr({opacity:0,width:80,height:80});
school.animate({opacity:1,width:100,height:100},2000)
```

I want to animate these objects using *Mina* so that they can be executed one after another.
Objects should fade in one by one.
how to do that?

This code gives no errors, however they all come at once instead of one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a callback in animate function, use it to call the next animation.

```js
var 
s = Snap(300,300),
circle7 = s.circle(130,90,5).attr({fill:"#fff",opacity:0}),
circle8 = s.circle(155,90,5).attr({fill:"#fff",opacity:0}),
circle9 = s.circle(180,90,5).attr({fill:"#fff",opacity:0}),
circle10 = s.circle(205,90,5).attr({fill:"#fff",opacity:0}),
circle11 = s.circle(230,90,5).attr({fill:"#fff",opacity:0}),
circle12 = s.circle(255,90,5).attr({fill:"#fff",opacity:0}),
duration = 500,
props = {fill:"#00f",opacity:1};

/*
var anim = function() {  circle.animate({fill:"#00f",opacity:1}, duration,mina.linear,anim1);}
var anim1 = function() { circle1.animate({fill:"#00f",opacity:1},duration,mina.linear,anim2);}
var anim2 = function() { circle2.animate({fill:"#00f",opacity:1},duration,mina.linear,anim3);}
var anim3 = function() { circle3.animate({fill:"#00f",opacity:1},duration,mina.linear,anim4);}
var anim4 = function() { circle4.animate({fill:"#00f",opacity:1},duration,mina.linear,anim5);}
var anim5 = function() { circle5.animate({fill:"#00f",opacity:1},duration,mina.linear,anim6);}
var anim6 = function() { circle6.animate({fill:"#00f",opacity:1},duration,mina.linear,anim7);}
*/

var anim7 = function() { circle7.animate(props,duration,mina.linear,anim8);}
var anim8 = function() { circle8.animate(props,duration,mina.linear,anim9);}
var anim9 = function() { circle9.animate(props,duration,mina.linear,anim10);}
var anim10= function() { circle10.animate(props,duration,mina.linear,anim11);}
var anim11= function() { circle11.animate(props,duration,mina.linear,anim12);}
var anim12= function() { circle12.animate(props,duration,mina.linear);};


anim7();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing there that makes them animate in a sequence.

The way to animate in a sequence is to use a callback, which is part of the animate() method. So you can do...

```
circle1.animate({ fill:"#0000FF" }, 1000, mina.linear, callbackFunc2 );

function callbackFunc2() {
   circle2.animate({ fill:"#0000FF" }, 1000, mina.linear, callbackFunc3 );
}

function callbackFunc3()...
```

And so on. Naturally that can feel a bit clunky when you have a lot, so I find it useful to add a sequence plugin to help. For example [here](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframe)

```
function nextFrame ( el, frameArray,  whichFrame ) {
    if( whichFrame >= frameArray.length ) { return }
    el.animate( frameArray[ whichFrame ].animation, frameArray[ whichFrame ].dur, nextFrame.bind( null, el, frameArray, whichFrame + 1 ) );

}
```

I also extended it a bit and suggested it [here](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/515) (see the jsfiddle) which may be of use, if you're doing a lot of them.

Comment: Good suggestion.... First answer also did work for me and yours is concise.... Thank you